# Как сократить выводимое значение базы данных android

Tags: android, mysql, sql

Сам код:

```
private void openFile() {
    db = sqlHelper.getReadableDatabase();// открываем подключение к базе данных
    userCursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE, null);
    String[] headers = new String[]{COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_YEAR};
    userAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,
            userCursor, headers, new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2}, 0);
    listView.setAdapter(userAdapter);
}
```

Если писать вот так много символов:

```
 db.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+ TABLE +" (" + COLUMN_NAME
            + ", " + COLUMN_YEAR  + ") VALUES ('Том Смит', 19asgdahsgdagsdiagsidagsiydgaigsdiagisdia);");
```

То при выводе получается вот такое значение:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А какой тип данных у колонки? `String`?

Comment: @Romag в чём вопрос?

Comment: Как сделать так что бы выводилось только первые 10 символов из записи например.

Comment: Вы хотите узнать, как число в последнем айтеме выводить не в экспоненциальной форме, а в простой?

Comment: Да. Как сократить значения до простого отражения в 10 символов к примеру.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. проверяйте на валидность входящие данные, год должен быть корректным.
2. или более долгое решение. напишите свой класс который extends SimpleCursorAdapter . И в TextView где проставляется год, используйте форматирование, например

   .setText(String.format("%" + maxlength + "d", year));